# my_string[0] throws string index out of range in Python

Tags: python, string

I am extracting api calls from a log as strings, storing them in a file then in another process reading them from this file.
I want to catch the lines that exist, which length is above 5 and starting with a double quote.

```
 if (input_string):
    if (len(input_string)>5):
        if (input_string[0] == '"'):
```

Throws the following exception:

```
File "/home/api_calls_simulator.py", line 58, in doWork
    if (input_string[0] == '"'):
IndexError: string index out of range
```

input_string comes from:

```
call_file = open("./myfile.txt")
for input_string in call_file:
```

example of matching line:

```
"/api/v2/product/id/2088?user_name=website&key=secretkey&format=json" 200 2790 "-" hit
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: Did you try using `somestring.startswith()`

Comment: could you give us the value of input_string or anything that might help us help you?

Comment: put a print before last check of whether it starts with a double quote and check what was the value of `input_string` at that instant when error was thrown. also use `somestring.startswith()` as Lukasz mentioned above. also three nested `if`'s could be combined in single line no need to nest them

Comment: Are you sure `input_string` is a string and not just some bogus collection?

Comment: startswith works but I don't get why the regular index doesn't work.
I can't print as it is processing millions of rows and only a few are faulty, but it is multi threaded therefore I can't catch the right print.
I have edited so you can see how I generate input_string

Comment: Try putting this code around a try-except block and print the string in case of an error. Also, are those really strings? AFAIK strings are immutable in python, so you shouldn't be able to affect its content, but if is some other class, another thread could change it.

Comment: Use a try/catch block, to try the if and catch the exception, and in the exception print the `input_string` and it's type.

Comment: ok so the print gives empty lines, I also test the type and I get str, but then how can you explain that len(input_string) returns values about 100+ but print doesn't output anything

Comment: Can you edit the post with examples of lines that match the criteria?

Comment: I've run the code you provided with a test.txt file that has a couple of lines including the example from you. It seems to work just as intended, it might have to do with the file you're reading.

Comment: yes very probably, but for line in call_file: should return me strings ?
it is a ubuntu log file, pure plain text